# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid Cell Format

Tags: oracle-apex

Basic question please, I have an IG.
Trying to format a column using the following:

```
SELECT
   CASE
    WHEN my_number <= 3 THEN 'u-color-7-bg'
    WHEN my_number > 3  THEN 'u-color-8-bg'
   END some_color
FROM my_table
```

I'm modifying the resulting column 'some_color' to be an HTML Expression type.
On its HTML Expression part I have:
< span style="color: &SOME_COLOR.">&MY_NUMBER.< /span>

But it doesn't work, no format is getting applied whatsoever.
Can anybody give me a hand please?

Comment: Your solution works for classic reports and interactive reports. Interactive Grids are completely different. Download the "Interactive Grid Cookbook" [here](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2019/11/04/apex-ig-cookbook-update-for-19-2/). It has an example of "Cell Style based on data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u-color-xx are CSS classes not actual colors. It should work if you try `<span class="&SOME_COLOR.">&MY_NUMBER.</span>` instead.

Alternatively you can use CSS-Variables defined by APEX in newer versions like this: `<span style="background: var(--u-color-35)">&MY_NUMBER.</span>`

Comment: thanks! I know it was silly but I couldn't solve it on my own. It's working now!

Comment: Great! There are no silly questions :).